# out bound virtual ip for azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, load-balancing, virtual-ip-address

i can see that virtual ip for a service can be fixed, but it has nothing about the outbound ip and port . in other words -- When i send something like a response from my virtual machines do they have the same source ip and port or have different ips based to the virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Your VMs will be presented to the internet using the VIP you reserve.  The VIP is on the wrapping Cloud Service which also provides load balancing for the inbound ports. See here for more information: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/07/18/static-dip-request-vip-reservation-on-microsoft-azure/